# Cloning CVPixelBuffer - how to?

Tags: ios, ios5, core-video

Say I have some pixel buffer associated with variable:

CVPixelBufferRef a;

I want to **clone** that buffer with all it contents and assign the cloned one to another variable.
What is the most correct and fast way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far I did not find a better solution than memcpy().  Hope it copies all the needed data.